# Getting group members from group using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/251/) there are two tables(in the users tab),one for showing group members and another for showing group names.In the fiddle some of the already created groups are test3,spanwave and koio.The members of spanwave are namenayak and ajay.Similarily the members for koio are steven and name.Now suppose If I click spanwave then from the left side table the check boxes of namenayak and ajay will be selected.And similarily if I click the koio group then steven and name will be selected.This is working fine for newly created groups but I dont know how to get the same working of existing groups.

**newly created groups** click more than 2 checkboxes then a group button will appear,now click the group button then an alert pop will appear asking you to enter group name.Enter some name and click ok.Then that name will now appear on the right side group table.Now clcik the group name then those members will be selected.I want to the same from existing groups also.Please tell me how.

Javascript code for newly created groups

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn2',function () {
        var groupmems="";
        var grpname;
    var email=new Array();
        var username=new Array();
        var mobno=new Array();
        var creat_group = prompt("Name your group??");
        grpname=creat_group;

        if (creat_group) {
            console.log(obj);

            $("#groupsTable").append('<tr id="groupTr' + groupTrCount + '"></tr>');
            $tr=$("#groupTr" + groupTrCount);
            var sCheckbox = new Array();
            $('#mytable tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i) {               
                    sCheckbox.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
                    alert("hello " +sCheckbox);
            });
             var ds = (sCheckbox.length > 0) ? sCheckbox.join(",") : "";
            $tr.append("<td data-selected='"+ds+"'> <input type='button' id='btn5' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' value='"+creat_group+"'/>  </td>");
            var userColumn = "<ul>";
            $('#mytable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
                var count=0;
                var arrid=0;
                $(this).find('td').each(function() {

                    //your ajax call goes here
                    if(count == 1){

                        userColumn+= "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>" ;
                                                username[arrid]=$(this).html();

                        groupmems=groupmems+$(this).html()+":";


                    }
                  if(count==2)
                    {
                                                email[arrid]=$(this).html();

                        groupmems=groupmems+$(this).html()+":";


                    }
                    if(count==3)
                    {
                                                mobno[arrid]=$(this).html();

                        groupmems=groupmems+$(this).html()+";";


                    }
                    count++;
                    });
                arrid++;
            });
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
alert("group name "+grpname);
             alert(groupmems);
//ajax for group insert
            $.ajax(
               {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "GroupInsert.jsp", //Your full URL goes here
                   data: { group: groupmems,groupname:grpname},
                   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                       alert(data);                  
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR){
                       alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                   }
               });
            userColumn+="<ul>";
            $tr.append("<td >" +userColumn+ "</td>");
        groupTrCount++;
        }        
    });
```

Comment: awesome fiddle!  some folks could learn from you on how to ask a question :D.  And I could probably learn on how to make a relevant comment but this was really noteworthy submission so thanks!

Comment: darn your fiddle seems broken.  Not the only problem but note that ajax requests don't work as is in jsfiddle.  if you have some sample data you can fake it -- see the jsfiddle docs on how to fake it.   **Now, on to your problem:** could the problem be that you need a _delegated_ handler on a container DOM element (a container that would contain both new and existing users and the existing selector would work for newly added elements)  That way as new elements are added they "inherit" or "are delegated" the handler.  This works because of _event bubbling_ from children elements to parents.

Comment: @gillyspy Thanks for your repsonse,I just wanted to know the steps.Well I posted the whole code in fiddle because If I misplace some part here and there then whole of my app does not work.well do you know how to solve ?

Comment: can you paste an example of the ajax response in a comment of the fiddle?

Comment: @gillyspy ajax response mean?If you want the ajax calling page then I can give but its in jsp

Comment: @gillyspy do you have any solutions?

Comment: i was thinking if you included some of the missing items the fiddle could work. can you describe more about diff b/t existing and new groups?  In your fiddle how can i identify what is a new or existing groups?   also you say "In the fiddle some of the already created groups are test3,spanwave and koio" and then you say "if I click the koio group then steven and name will be selected."   I would interpret that to mean that existing groups work fine.  But then you say "This is working fine for newly created groups but I dont know how to get the same working of existing groups." i'm confused :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42698/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-gillyspy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your present data you need `id` of the user

Example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc9d57/1

By the sql output data.. your code should be like

```
<tr>
   <td data-selected="{UIDS}">{GROUPNAME}</td>
</tr>
```

**Example:**

```
<tr>
   <td data-selected="40,46">koio</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td data-selected="48,50">spanwave</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you come to discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42698/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-gillyspy?

Comment: do you this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561661/ok-button-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: If you are free can you come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44375/discussion

Comment: can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037065/how-to-append-the-checked-boxes-name