# How to append the checked boxes name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBPB6/18/)
There is a `To` and when its pressed a modal dialog box appears.The dialog box has a drop down menu.When `groups` or `users` drop down is selected then a table with check boxes appear.Please tell me how to append the check boxes name when check boxes are selected or delete the delete the appended names when the check box is unselected.

to append I have to like this

```
$('#ToAdd').append('hi');
```

But I dont know how to call this and get the values.please help

Example

Suppose groups menu is selected and from the below check boxes,1st row is selected Then `hhh` will be displayed in the span

```
<span id="ToAdd"></span>
```

Comment: can you be specific than a lots of code. I mean checkbox names codes in your question would be better.

Comment: it means you want the members name or the name you placed in check boz input element

Comment: @C-link see Suppose you selected the groups table and after that you selected 1st check boxes then I want the hhh to be displayed in the span

Comment: @C-link Hope you understood now

Comment: Do you want the attribute `name` or do you want the `Username`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche For the table id="mytable" i want ajay from this `<tr id="5"><td><input data-id="5" type="checkbox" name="mytr5"></td><td>ajay</td>` and from the table id="groupsTable" i want hhh from `<tr id="hhh">` if 1st row is selected from both the tables.Hope you understand

Comment: @OlafDietsche why deleted your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I moved the two tables `#mytable` and `#groupTable` to the dialog

```html
<div class="tab-content ">
    <div class="tab-pane " id="users">Users
        <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered">
...
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="groups">Groups
        <table id="groupsTable" class="table table-bordered">
...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This simplifies switching between the two tabs

```js
$('.select').on('change', function () {
    var tablink = '#' + $(this).val();
    $('a[href="' + tablink + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Now, you can easily pick up the checked names

```js
function collect_users() {
    var users = [];
    $('input:checked', '#mytable').closest('td').next('td').each(function() {
        users.push($(this).text());
    });

    $('#ToAdd').text(users.join(', '));
}

$('#mytable input:checkbox').click(collect_users);
```

Similar goes for the `#groupTable`.

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBPB6/30/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The fiddle you provided does not show the checkboxes when I select group or user drop down menu.

Comment: @JqueryLearner No, it shows the names, of course. This is why I asked, if you want the `Username`. And downvoting doesn't help here, btw.

Comment: Hey I didnt downvote.I can not treat this way(by downvoting) who tried to help me.

Comment: see when I click the To buttnon, a modal dialog box appears and drop down menu.When i change select the users or groups drop down menu nothing happens

Comment: @Pilot Do you have gmail?

Comment: can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084748/how-to-remove-checkboxes-by-deleting-from-input-textfield

Answer (score 1):

Add your checkboxes inside some `div / form` and handle on change event ,

```
$('#container input:checkbox[name=groupname]').on('change', function (event) {
   $("#Toadd").html('');
   $('#container input:checkbox[name=groupname]:checked').each(function() {
       $("#Toadd").append($(this).attr('data-id'));
   }
});
```

### [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9rHP/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Can you please give a fiddle?

Comment: i tried your way but its not working.Can you please tell me what else i need to change

Comment: I am weak in jquery so asked you to update my fiddle but you gave another fiddle

Comment: @JqueryLearner I am sorry but your code is quite cludgy.. all you need is to copy and paste this code.Ask anything that you didnt understand

Comment: In the fiddle posted in the question.After pressing the ok button I want the selecte names in the texfield also.How to do>

Comment: @JqueryLearner handle on click event for ok button call `function(checked name) {}` on click of ok buttom which will populate your text box.

Comment: It would be nice If you please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBPB6/29/)

You have to bind the change event each time the table is dynamically created. Sorry about the previous fiddle.

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']", "#mytable1").on('change', function (event) {
        $("#ToAdd").html('');
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked", "#mytable1").each(function() {
           $("#ToAdd").append($(this).parent().next().text() + " ");           
       });
   });
```

You can create same thing for groups if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not working.the selected check boxes does not show

Comment: As your code you will have to select User or Group after the model is loaded. Try changing the select box.

Comment: Yes I changed but its not working.Is it working for you?Does names gets appended?

Comment: Note:**I didnt downvote** 
This is noting relevant to que. Question is to how to append checked names.Second thing why are this array created?.

Comment: All what you want is to show checkbox selected names in the dialog? there was a misunderstanding in the question, sorry

Comment: @madushak yes this is my requirement

Comment: @JqueryLearner i have updated the answer. sorry about the previous one.

Comment: @madushak I think you have not updated the fiddle because now also not working

Comment: Click on To button. Select groups and then select Users (to fire change event of the select list). Then click on the checkbox. I think it should be what you need

Comment: @madushak wow nice,Its working +1.well it works for users only

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44933/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-madushak)

Comment: @madushak I have some query,can you come to discussion?